# Strange characters on MySQL Point column

Tags: mysql

I have a POINT column to store coordinates, and here is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO _coordinates_test (coordinates) VALUES(POINT(59.356125477261266, -2.8759361517393898))
```

But here is what i get on the column (coordinates):

```
   …•­M@“Ö(ÐêÀ
```

I also tried reading coordinates like this:

```
SELECT POINT(59.356125477261266, -2.8759361517393898)
```

I also tried converting a regular coordinates string to a POINT, like this:

```
SELECT ST_PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', '59.356125477261266 -2.8759361517393898' , ')'))
```

Here is the CREATE TABLE query:

```
CREATE TABLE `_coordinates_test` (
    `coordinates` POINT NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

The result is always the same, those strange characters.

Is there some issue with the encoding (currently utf8mb4_unicode_ci) or does POINT not support coordinates ?

Could it be that my MySQL Client software (HeidiSQL) is not reading the data correctly ?

MY USE CASE: Im trying to store coordinates in that column so i can calculate the distance (in meters) between different physical objects.

Comment: Can you share the create table?

Comment: @nbk i have just added it

Comment: Yes i have just found that and implemented it

Comment: Usually we save the latitude and longitide thakeeps it human readable in msql workbench  you get the a binary

Answer (score 1):

As per the MySQL official documentation, use `ST_X()` for x-coordinate and `ST_Y()` for y-coordinate when reading a Point data type.

```
mysql> SELECT ST_X(Point(15, 20));
15
```

Refer to below for more details
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_st-x

Comment: Yes thats what im using now, and it works

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the strange characters did actually represent the POINT value, and so it was not corrupted (i thought it was) but can be shown as text using ST_TEXT(coordinates).

So:

```
SELECT ST_ASTEXT(POINT(59.356125477261266, -2.8759361517393898))
```

will show the correct value

I can then manipulate the values as i want, using ST_X or ST_Y, and i can perform the measuring i need using ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE

Comment: This is producing: "FUNCTION fiddle.ST_TEXT does not exist" (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/mRuAeafN)

Comment: Yes i meant to write ST_ASTEXT, i just corrected, thank you for pointing that out